# How to get an integer value using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: webdriver

```
WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.grtjewels.com");
    driver.findElement(By.id("CollapsiblePanel1txt")).click();
    e=( driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='CollapsiblePanel1']/div/p[5]")).getAttribute("value"));
    System.out.println("The output is " +e);
```

I have to print the Gold value....Can any one please help me out

Comment: Can you explain we still clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a sync issue
See the use of **wait until element is visible** below

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.grtjewels.com");

    driver.findElement(By.id("CollapsiblePanel1txt")).click();
    WebElement e = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='CollapsiblePanel1']/div/p[5]"));

    //Waiting for the element to be visible
    Wait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(e));

    System.out.println("The output is " +e.getText());
}
```

Comment: Great its working. I was struggling with it for a quiet long time.But a small change in the coding WebDriverWait wait =new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to only print the selected values of the element? Did you try doing driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='CollapsiblePanel1']/div/p[5]")).getText()